# How to disable multi preview feature introduced in Android-Studio 3.6

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.6

Is there a way to disable the new multi preview of layout added in Android-Studio 3.6?

- I think it takes too much time to load.
- Last but not least, it seems not possible to change the local and the theme applied to the preview, as it was possible before.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can just remove it from sidebar and set view mode to "Split" while editing your layout file as it was before in Android Studio 3.5.

Comment: It seems to have been automatically disabled on Android Studio 3.6.1

Comment: is there any way to get it back in 3.6.1?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it gets better in AndroidStudio 4.0

Also this setting is useful:

[image]